# Performance with conditional statements in Objective-C and NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Basically my dictionary looks like:

`object:[NSNumber numberWithBool:] key: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:ID]`

I want to add objects to a NSMutableDictionary if they don't exist already.  I also want to overwrite any values of NO with YES if there are two IDs that are the same and one value is a YES.

e.g.

```
ID:5, YES
ID:5, NO
ID:5, YES
```

I want the result to be `ID:5 YES` in my dictionary.  I do this:

```
if ([dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:conditionsListID]] != nil) {
   [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:theValue forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:conditionsListID];
else {
  if (theValue) {
       [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:theValue forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:conditionsListID];

  }
}
}
```

I was wondering if it matters if I even check if the value that exists already has NO, or if I just overwrite it if my new value has YES or not since in the end, YES is what I want.  Is there really any difference between the two?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to explicitly record the `NO` values, or is non-presence in the dictionary sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call setObject:forKey: and the dictionary will take care of the logic you want. According to the API docs:

"If aKey already exists in the dictionary, the dictionary’s previous value object for that key is sent a release message and anObject takes its place."